# Is there a minimal legal ground clearance to use an international airport?

Tags: aircraft-design

The question arises while I was looking at the evolution of the B737 engines and the lower and lower space available between ground and engines. Then I realized that ground clearance is also low for other small airliners we can find in international airport (e.g. Embraer 175, ATR-42,...).

I imagine ground clearance is designed taking into account tailstrike, FOD, runway irregularities.

My question is: can an aircraft legally be excluded from using an airport because of its ground clearance?

Let's restrict this question to international airports and airliners transporting at least 8 passengers

Comment: Are you interested only in airliners?  And what does the ground clearance apply to, engines/propellors or fuselage?

Comment: @jamesqf I already restricted the question to airliners transporting at least 8 passengers. I'm interested in both fuselage and engines (i.e. anything that can touch the ground and is not made to)

Comment: I don't know whether they've ever been used as airliners, but the Aero Commander family has a pretty low fuselage ground clearance, and some models carry more than 8 passengers: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aero_Commander_500_family

Answer (score 3):

For propellers, there is a minimum ground clearance according to the [EASA Easy Access Rules for Normal, Utility, Aerobatic and Commuter Category Aeroplanes (CS-23)](https://www.easa.europa.eu/sites/default/files/dfu/CS-23%20Initial%20issue.pdf):

> **CS 23.925 Propeller clearance**
>
> Propeller clearances with the aeroplane at the most adverse combination of weight and centre of
>   gravity and with the propeller in the most adverse pitch position, may not be less than the following:
>
> (a) Ground clearance. There must be a clearance of at least 18 cm (7 in) (for each aeroplane with
>   nose wheel landing gear) or 23 cm (9 in) (for each aeroplane with tail wheel landing gear)
>   between each propeller and the ground with the landing gear statically deflected and in the
>   level, normal take-off, or taxying attitude, whichever is the most critical. In addition, for each
>   aeroplane with conventional landing gear struts using fluid or mechanical means for absorbing
>   landing shocks, there must be positive clearance between the propeller and the ground in the
>   level take-off attitude with the critical tyre completely deflated and the corresponding landing
>   gear strut bottomed. Positive clearance for aeroplanes using leaf spring struts is shown with a
>   deflection corresponding to 1.5g.
>
> (b) Aft mounted propellers. In addition to the clearance specified in sub-paragraph (a) an aeroplane
>   with an aft mounted propeller must be designed such that the propeller will not contact the
>   runway surface when the aeroplane is in the maximum pitch attitude attainable during normal
>   take-off and landings.

So **18cm** seems to be the minimum ground clearance for propellers on most aircraft (e.g. ATR-42).

It is hard to prove a negative, but the section about turbojets and turbofan engines does not list any minimum.